Issue with Play Store Compatibility for Flutter App
I recently released an application on the Google Play Store. The app passed review successfully and was published without any issues. However, upon attempting to install it on various Android devices via the Play Store, I encountered the error message:
App wasn't compatible with this device
This error occurs consistently on all Android phones I tested. Upon further investigation, I discovered that the "Supported devices" section in the Play Store Console shows 0 devices out of all.
Here are the relevant sections of my manifest and build.gradle files:Here is my manifest


<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
        tools:ignore="SelectedPhotoAccess" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:label= "@string/app_name"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.env.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="$$$$$$$$$$$$"/>
            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
    </application>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


Build.gradle

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "######"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0')
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    }

Here is the supported devices 0 showing in Console

I've verified that the minSdkVersion is set to 21 and other configurations seem to be in order. Can anyone offer insights into why the app is showing as incompatible with all devices and how I can resolve this issue?

If I remember correctly the "Supported Devices" allows you to manually select devices you want to support (independently of the hardware and other limitations that may prevent an installation) . If you don't chose a device there then the app can not be installed on any device just as you have configured it. So you have to select the devices you want to support or simply enable all devices.

In Console, for .aab bundle. it is showing 0 devices. i haven't configured any in console. Im new to Android things.

It looks like your build.gradle is not complete.
First, you must sign your app and generate a key.properties.
Here is an example of Build.gradle signed and published on Google Play.
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com........"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
//            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
//        }
//    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            //useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation(composeBom)
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:21.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")}


signingConfigs.release I have signing key generated and published release app. for simplicity just removed in this question.
